# Homomorphic image of a nilpotent group is nilpotent

Tags: abstract-algebra

Is it true that an image of a nilpotent group under a homomorphic function is nilpotent?
In that case, how am I going to show this?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Nilpotence is defined in terms of certain words (iterated commutators) vanishing (having value the identity) identically on the group. Homomorphisms preserve this property.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Do you know the correspondence theorem for subgroups?  You can think of a homomorphic image of $G$ as a quotient $G/N$.  If $G$ is nilpotent then the lower central series terminates.  You just have to show that the lower central series for $G/N$ terminates.

Answer (score 0):

It is true. If $G$ is a nilpotent group, $G$ has a central series $\{ Z_i\}$. Let f be a homomorphism from $G$ to $H$. Then we can show that $\{ f(Z_i) \}$ is a central series of $H$.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Your answer adds nothing new to the answer that was accepted more than siz years ago.