# Is the class of all nilpotent groups closed under homomorphic images?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, quotient-group, nilpotent-groups

Suppose $H$ is a normal subgroup of a nilpotent group $G$. Does it imply, that  $\frac{G}{H}$ is nilpotent?

I do not know how to prove this. Could you help me, please?

Comment: What definition of nilpotency are you deploying?

Comment: A tip: show some effort in order to get good answers, compatible with your definitions

Answer (score 2):

This is just the fourth isomorphism theorem, which says that if you have $N\trianglelefteq G$ and $N\le K\le G$ then the subgroups of $G/N$ are just the $K/N$. So take a central series, $\{A_i\}$, and project modulo $N$, and note that the condition $[G:A_i]\le A_i$ is satisfied on $[G/N: A_i/N]$ by construction. One might object and say that some of the $A_i$ of $G$ might be contained in $N$, but then that just produces a shorter central series for $G/N$, it doesn't change the facts for the ones that have $N\le A_i$.

Comment: I cannot understand the following line... note that the condition $[G:A_i]\le A_i$ is satisfied on $[G/N: A_i/N]$ by construction

Comment: @user8795 Let $\phi$ be the natural quotient map by $N$. Then just on a set level if $A\subseteq B$ we have $\phi(A)\subseteq\phi(B)$.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using upper central ($\zeta_i(G)$) and lower central series ($\gamma_{i+1}(G)$) a hint: $\gamma_{i+1}(G/H)=\gamma_{i+1}(G)H/H$ for every integer $i \geq 0$.

Answer (score 1):

Subgroups and homomorphic images of nilpotent groups are nilpotent. The proof depends on your definition of a nilpotent group, which is usually by the upper or lower central series. In particular, quotients are nilpotent again, see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/329196/homomorphic-image-of-a-nilpotent-group-is-nilpotent) on MSE (including the comment of Qiaochu Yuan: "Nilpotence is defined in terms of certain words (iterated commutators) vanishing (having value the identity) identically on the group. Homomorphisms preserve this property").

Answer (score 0):

Another approach and hint, if $G$ is **finite** and if $P \in Syl_p(G)$, then $P \unlhd G$. Since $H \unlhd G$, also $PH \unlhd G$ and hence $PH/H \unlhd G/H$, and $PH/H \in Syl_p(G/H)$.